# add more than 1 value to each key in dictionary on python

Tags: python

lets say i have list of K elements:

```
['0.mnet', '1.mnet', '2.mnet', '3.mnet', '4.mnet']
```

i want that each element will be a key in dictionary,
in my h.w, if there a link between a file to other file, i want to add this to my dictionary.
for example:

```
Page number 0
There's a link below to page 4:
<<4.mnet>>
And this here is page 3
 <<3.mnet>>
```

what i want to get:
{'0.mnet': 4, '0.mnet': 3}

i missing something in this line:

```
                    linkofpages[pages[i]] = k
```

code:

```
def load_mininet(net_path):
size = 5
# list of lists, each list we have size pages, in each page we have maximal sqrt(size) of links
pages = []
linkofpages = {}
for i in range(size):
    file = net_path + str(i) + '.mnet'
    p = Path(file)
    pages.append(file)
    with p.open() as f:
        content = f.read()
        print(content)
        for k in range(size):
            if "<<" + str(k) + ".mnet>>" in content and i != k:
                print("from page", i, " to page ", k, " have a link")
                linkofpages[pages[i]] = k
print(pages)
print(linkofpages)
```

thanks.

Comment: `{'0.mnet': 4, '0.mnet': 3}` is not a value dictionary in Python. Keys must be unique. (If they aren't, when you type `x=linkofpages['0.mnet']` what value would be assigned to x ? 3?4? something else?)
But why not change your dictionary so that for each key, a list of linked pages will be stored instead. i.e. `{'0.mnet': [3,4]}`

Comment: `what i want to get: {'0.mnet': 4, '0.mnet': 3}`  You cannot have duplicate keys in a dict.  Since you are not clear about how you plan to use this, nor about the use case that builds the dict, we can't help you too much.

Answer (score 1):

Comments above are correct about how `{'0.mnet': 4, '0.mnet': 3}` is impossible in a python dict because keys must be unique.

I would suggest the following alternative that may work for you:
You could assign the list [3, 4] as the value for '0.mnet', like

```
{'0.mnet', [3, 4]}
```

And you could access both elts of [3, 4] by indexing over the value:

```
d['0.mnet'][1]
>>> 3
```

```
d['0.mnet'][2]
>>> 4
```

Comment: yes, this is what i want to get.
can you tell me what i need to do for it?

Comment: `d['0.mnet'] = [3, 4]` so you have `{'0.mnet': [3, 4]}` ?